# Cisco Route-Map Object Tracking for Default-Information

Tags: cisco, routing, cisco-ios

I am tasked to do conditonally advertise a default route using RIP only if a specific IP address is ICMP reachable. (Yes, CCIE study, not a real network design).

My idea was to use the [track object matching](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_pi/configuration/15-mt/iri-15-mt-book/iri-pbr-match-track-object.html) feature to accomplish this task:

```
R1#show run | s route-map|sla|track|router rip
track 1 ip sla 1
router rip
 version 2
 network 150.1.0.0
 network 155.1.0.0
 default-information originate route-map RELIABLE_DEFAULT
 no auto-summary
ip sla 1
 icmp-echo 155.1.7.7
 frequency 5
ip sla schedule 1 life forever start-time now
route-map RELIABLE_DEFAULT permit 10
 match track  1
```

The track object and SLA is actually working fine and the route-map is registered with the track object:

```
R1#show ip sla summary 
IPSLAs Latest Operation Summary
Codes: * active, ^ inactive, ~ pending

ID           Type        Destination       Stats       Return      Last
                                           (ms)        Code        Run 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
*1           icmp-echo   155.1.7.7         RTT=12      OK          0 seconds ago                                                                  

R1#show track 1
Track 1
  IP SLA 1 state
  State is Up
    2 changes, last change 00:08:55
  Latest operation return code: OK
  Latest RTT (millisecs) 12
  Tracked by:
    Route Map 0
```

This however does not work (no default route is advertised). Preferred solution is to use a dummy static route like this which is actually working.

```
ip sla 1
 frequency 5
 icmp-echo 155.1.7.7
ip sla schedule 1 start-time now life forever
track 1 ip sla 1
! 
ip route 169.254.0.1 255.255.255.255 Null0 track 1
!
ip prefix-list DUMMY_ROUTE seq 5 permit 169.254.0.1/32
!
route-map RELIABLE_DEFAULT permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list DUMMY_ROUTE
! 
router rip
 default-information originate route-map RELIABLE_DEFAULT
```

I understand why this solution works, however I do not understand why mine does not. Any ideas?

Comment: Well waza-ari, who got it right, if anyone?  My answer (EEM) or OzNetNerd's comment that points to you supportforums.cisco.com difficult to understand solution of how to use a bogus IP address hack with IP SLA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the default information originate command is incompatible with IP SLA.

You've probably already seen this, but this Cisco forum post talks about using a bogus static route (the same method you used to get it to work).

https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/116336/ospf-reliable-conditional-default-routing

Using this method means that the default information originate command is not interfacing with IP SLA directly.

Comment: Why is it the wrong technology? It works and I posted also posted a reference link. Can you please do the same for your EEM suggestion?

Comment: Sure.  Here's a [beginners guide](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/blogs/network-sheriff/2009/06/19/writing-your-first-eem-applet) to get you started.  EEM is the way to go.

Comment: To be fair, I shouldn't say wrong technology.  It's just that EEM is very feature rich and this is what I see being used these days.

Comment: I know how to write EEM scripts. What I meant was, do you have any references that demonstrate others using EEM for this scenario? There should be plenty of them given that you're suggesting it's the better method.

Comment: [Here are several of them.](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=eem%20default%20route%20injection)

Comment: That's just a Google search, not a specific reference like the one I provided. At the end of the day it's up to the OP how they do it. As mentioned previously, I'd prefer to use the commands supplied by Cisco rather than write my own script. Why try to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Your example does not Use RIP (nor mine).  Default info originate relates to the routing protocol, not IP SLA.  Right?  The reason it's hard to find examples specific to RIP is becuase RIP is rarely used in the real world compared to OSPF/EIGRP.  EEM allows you to script code, so it's compatible with whatever the IOS supports.

Answer (score 1):

Some options (like Match track) in route maps are there just for PBR and not for other usages, in that case you need the dummy route as you are using a Route-map which does not work with the track option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know of any documentation which explicitly states which options are allowed in which context?

Answer (score -3):

I don't know about the exam, but in the real world something like this would be done using [Cisco IOS Embedded Event Manager (EEM)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/ios-nx-os-software/ios-embedded-event-manager-eem/index.html).

See Also [EEM script to report routing table change](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11368256/eem-script-report-routing-table-change)

```
event manager applet route-table-monitor

 event routing network 0.0.0.0/0 ge 1

 action 1.0 syslog msg "Route changed: Type: $_routing_type, Network: $_routing_network, Mask/Prefix: $_routing_mask, Protocol: $_routing_protocol, GW: $_routing_lastgateway, Intf: $_routing_lastinterface"
```

Comment: Downvoter can't provide any feedback?  Or, is it the resident troll(s) vandalize this site again...  I bet the downvoter has never even heard of EEM.

Comment: [Cisco IOS Release 12.4T](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipapp/configuration/12-4t/iap-12-4t-book/iap-eot.html) : "Enhanced Object Tracking **(EOT) is now integrated with Embedded Event Manager (EEM)** to allow EEM to report on status change of a tracked object and to allow EOT to track EEM objects."

Comment: Why would you go to the trouble of writing a script when Cisco themselves  provides the commands you need?

Comment: EEM offers more features.  That's why we use it.

Comment: Sure it supports more features, but again, why write something custom if you don't need the extra features? It's like buying a bus when all you need is a family car. Sure, it can seat more people, but why do it? I prefer to keep things simple. It makes troubleshooting easier. Besides, a Python script would provide even more features than EEM. The reason why didn't suggest it though I'd because just like EEM, it's overkill for the task at hand.

Comment: "in the real world" I'd like notification of primary WAN link outage.  EEM can auto-alert me via email.

Comment: So can SNMP. Another feature provided by Cisco and supported by countless number of paid for, free and open source monitoring apps. As I mentioned previously, I'd prefer to use the features provided by Cisco (and other vendors) rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: SNMP?  You mean with EEM?  I think EEM in addition to having more features is easier to script and understand than using a 'bogus IP address' hack.  Don't you?

Comment: No, I meant SNMP.  While using  a bogus IP is strange, I'd still prefer to use Cisco's own commands than write my own scripts. If someone else needs to work on the router they can look at Cisco's documentation go find out what the commands do. However, they won't have that same luxury if you write your own script. Anyway, as mentioned previously, let's just leave it up to the OP to decide how they'd like to do it.

Comment: SNMP is not used for this.  Never seen it.  It may be possible but I've never seen it done.  EEM I've seen plenty of.

Comment: You've never seen SNMP used in conjunction with a monitoring app to alert on link down events? It's extremely common. All engineers I know use it and set it up for their clients if they haven't got a solution deployed already.

Comment: To alert, yes; but to conditionally inject routes, no.  Although I think it could be done.  There were security issues around SNMP v1&2.  I think v3 fixes that.

Comment: I wasn't saying SNMP can be used to inject routes. Re-read our conversation above. You spoke about using EEM for alerting at which point I brought SNMP up.

Comment: I see.  I think it can be though?  EEM does notification without an external management server, ...an improvement, and a pretty cool feature.

Comment: Oh really, how does EEM notify without an external server?  How exactly do you know that EEM alerted without a syslog server?

Comment: @MikePennington I said "external management server".  You'll need to designate a mail server in the EEM script.  See [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=eem%20send%20an%20email).  SNMP email alerts would come from an SNMP *server* right?

Comment: Anybody with a clue already processes SNMP traps just like you must process mail.  If not, they need to set up a trap receiver for much more than merely the reasons mentioned in this increasingly absurd thread

Comment: @MikePennington People process SNMP traps with a network management server and emails with an email server.  Or, did I misunderstand you?  I appreciate your feedback but why are you characterizing this thread as absurd?  It's rude.  "Anybody with a clue already processes SNMP traps just like you must process mail" is wrong - they are 2 different servers.  I don't mind teaching y'all but anything more I am going to have to charge.  Email me directly.

Comment: I agree with Mike. This thread/these comments have gone on far longer than they should. As I've mentioned a couple of times already, let's just leave it up to the OP to decide how they'd like to solve the issue. In regards to implementing EEM scripts on every single individual device instead of using a single, central management server - it's your choice but I've never seen it done that way in all my years of being in IT, nor do I see the benefit. Anyway, this will be my last post on this thread as I feel the OP's question was answered long ago.